# Quickly format cells in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a reverse update on a spreadsheet to remove all formatting from a range of cells. iterating through the cells is quick enough however making the internal reference appears to slow the code down dramatically.

```
Set Rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A17:bb300")
For Each c1 In Rng1
    If c1.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid Then
        With c1.Interior
           .Pattern = xlNone
           .TintAndShade = 0
           .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next c1
```

Cheers

Comment: How about turning off/on Screen updating? `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then set it to `True` later in the code.

Comment: Your question says _"... remove all formatting  ..."_, but your code clears only a few format properties.  If you want to clear _all_ formatting, use `Rng1.ClearFormats`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can determine all the cells first, then format in one go:

```
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Set Rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A17:bb300")

For Each c1 In Rng1
    If c1.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid Then
        If Rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng2 = c1
        Else
            Set Rng2 = Union(Rng2, c1)
        End If
    End If
Next c1

With Rng2.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```