# Specific Macros run quicker

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there was any way to make this macros run quicker.

There is over 3500 rows and they are continually added to. Right now it takes about 30 seconds to complete (copied the module below).

I have around 10 other modules working by splitting up the "Main" sheet into specific tabs via a run button. In turn running this macro takes about 75 seconds which is far too long. Is there any way to run this quicker also?

```
Sub FillColumns()
Dim i, LastRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

LastRow = Sheets("Main").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 40 To LastRow 'start row number


If Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CURLEW C-Curlew Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "COOK-Anasuria allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SCOTER-Shearwater Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "MERGANSER-Shearwater Alloc." _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "PENGUIN-Brent C Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "STARLING-Shearwater Alloc." _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "HOWE-Nelson allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "ANASURIA-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT ALPHA-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT BRAVO-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT CHARLIE-Brent" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT CHARLIE-Flags" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT DELTA-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "U500-St Fergus" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BACTON SEAL-SEAL" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CURLEW-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "GANNET-Central" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "GANNET-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "MOSSMORRAN-Plants" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "U3000-St Fergus" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "NELSON-Forties Oil" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "NELSON-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SHEARWATER-Forties Oil" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SHEARWATER-SEAL" Then
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Else: Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End If

If Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CURLEW C-Curlew Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "COOK-Anasuria allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SCOTER-Shearwater Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "MERGANSER-Shearwater Alloc." _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "PENGUIN-Brent C Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "STARLING-Shearwater Alloc." _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "HOWE-Nelson allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "ANASURIA-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT ALPHA-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT BRAVO-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT CHARLIE-Brent" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT CHARLIE-Flags" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT DELTA-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "U500-St Fergus" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BACTON SEAL-SEAL" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CURLEW-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "GANNET-Central" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "GANNET-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "MOSSMORRAN-Plants" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "U3000-St Fergus" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "NELSON-Forties Oil" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "NELSON-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SHEARWATER-Forties Oil" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SHEARWATER-SEAL" Then
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Else: Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End If

If Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CURLEW C-Curlew Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "COOK-Anasuria allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SCOTER-Shearwater Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "MERGANSER-Shearwater Alloc." _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "PENGUIN-Brent C Allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "STARLING-Shearwater Alloc." _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "HOWE-Nelson allocation" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "ANASURIA-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT ALPHA-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT BRAVO-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT CHARLIE-Brent" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT CHARLIE-Flags" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BRENT DELTA-Flags Gas" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "U500-St Fergus" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "BACTON SEAL-SEAL" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "CURLEW-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "GANNET-Central" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "GANNET-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "MOSSMORRAN-Plants" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "U3000-St Fergus" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "NELSON-Forties Oil" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "NELSON-Fulmar" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SHEARWATER-Forties Oil" _
Or Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value = "SHEARWATER-SEAL" Then
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Else: Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End If
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378866/quickly-format-cells-in-excel) which I think will help you get what you want. The idea is to identify all the range you want to format first, then do the formatting in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the link @L42 . Everytime I tried something like this it kept giving me the error end if without block if so I just reverted back to what I had.

Comment: Hold on a sec, I'm trying to make something out of your code. I'll post in a bit.

Comment: This question should be asked at Code Review

Answer (score 3):

**Improvement #1.** The `Or` operator in VBA is eager, meaning that it will evaluate all the terms, even it could stop at the first that is `True` -- there's a first waste in your execution time. So, instead of `If expr1 Or expr2 Or ... Or exprn` you might want to use the equivalent form of `Select Case`, that will lazily evaluate its branching. For example, your first `If` will be transformed as:

```
Select Case Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value
Case "COOK-Anasuria allocation", "SCOTER-Shearwater Allocation", _
     "MERGANSER-Shearwater Alloc.", "PENGUIN-Brent C Allocation", _
     "STARLING-Shearwater Alloc.", "HOWE-Nelson allocation", _
     "ANASURIA-Fulmar", "BRENT ALPHA-Flags Gas", _
     "BRENT BRAVO-Flags Gas", "BRENT CHARLIE-Brent", _
     "BRENT CHARLIE-Flags", "BRENT DELTA-Flags Gas", _
     "U500-St Fergus", "BACTON SEAL-SEAL", _
     "CURLEW-Fulmar", "GANNET-Central", _
     "GANNET-Fulmar", "MOSSMORRAN-Plants", _
     "U3000-St Fergus", "NELSON-Forties Oil", _
     "NELSON-Fulmar", "SHEARWATER-Forties Oil", _
     "SHEARWATER-SEAL"
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Case Else
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
          Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
         Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End Select
```

**Improvement #2.** If you have some insight in how often the tested strings appear, you can use that info to shorten your execution time. The `Select` statement will test sequentially its `Cases`, then inside the `Case` branch its expressions; if you put the strings with biggest occurrence probability at the beginning of your `Select` statement, or at the beginning of your `Case` branch, you'll save useless comparisons.

**Improvement #3.** [The answer of VBlades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404443/2140173)

Comment: Thanks, would I just repeat the process for columns AA and AB? or is there a way to combine these all into one. That was a problem I couldnt work out as well

Comment: See the comment of @VBlades; you could put the "AA" & "AB" formatting in the same `Select` statement (if you're sure that the conditions are the same). Do not forget to put the code for `Else` branch also.

Comment: @CST-Link: Do you think a Replace of a string containing all the names with the cell A value then checking the Len of the resulting string against the original name string would be faster than even CASE? Crossed my mind.

Comment: @VBlades I'm not sure if it would improve the execution time. Usually operations that create/alter strings are much slower than simple comparisons. However, this is just a speculation on my part: it's worth testing it, as it is a clever hack.

Comment: @CST-Link: Ok, will give it a go if I can find some time.  Excellent answer as well, great explanation of your thinking process.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, try this:

```
Sub FillColumns()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim phrases
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    '~~> create an array of phrases
    phrases = Array("CURLEW C-Curlew Allocation", "COOK-Anasuria allocation", _
        "SCOTER-Shearwater Allocation", "MERGANSER-Shearwater Alloc.", _
        "PENGUIN-Brent C Allocation", "STARLING-Shearwater Alloc.", _
        "HOWE-Nelson allocation", "ANASURIA-Fulmar", _
        "BRENT ALPHA-Flags Gas", "BRENT BRAVO-Flags Gas", _
        "BRENT CHARLIE-Brent", "BRENT CHARLIE-Flags", _
        "BRENT DELTA-Flags Gas", "U500-St Fergus", _
        "BACTON SEAL-SEAL", "CURLEW-Fulmar", _
        "GANNET-Central", "GANNET-Fulmar", _
        "MOSSMORRAN-Plants", "U3000-St Fergus", _
        "NELSON-Forties Oil", "NELSON-Fulmar", _
        "SHEARWATER-Forties Oil", "SHEARWATER-SEAL")
    '~~> segregate the range to format using the phrases array
    With Sheets("Main")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 40 To LastRow
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, phrases, 0)) Then
                If rng1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng1 = .Range("Z" & i, "AB" & i)
                Else
                    Set rng1 = Union(rng1, .Range("Z" & i, "AB" & i))
                End If
            Else
                If rng2 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng2 = .Range("Z" & i, "AB" & i)
                Else
                    Set rng2 = Union(rng2, .Range("Z" & i, "AB" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    '~~> format the ranges in one go
    With rng1
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
    With rng2
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 56
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH. I've commented the important parts.
If something is unclear, just comment it out.

Comment: ++ L42 for the match i always forget that one

Comment: @mehow Yeah I almost deleted my answer when I saw your post. I thought it's the same. Then I saw it's not. Btw, this code runs less that 1 sec for 10k rows :D

Comment: @L42/ @me how. These work perfectly, thanks for the information. I never really understood ranges/arrays but with this code written out it makes far more sense to me that I can work with for my other modules.

Comment: @L42 just noticed one last thing, its no longer showing vertical border lines for cells in column "AA". I assume there is a quick fix to this. And yes, this has gone from about 30 seconds to essentially instantly.

Comment: @user3774309 Just tweak how you format the borders I think. :) Maybe change the color? For right and left that is.

Comment: @user3774309 Just add `.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous` as well as `(xlInsideHorizontal)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use only one IF statement - you have three checking for the same logic. The IF logic is complicated, so there is no point in replicating it.
2. Assign `Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value` to a string variable and use this variable in the code. I believe that each time you refer to `Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value` the engine goes through the path Workbook->Sheet->Cell->Value. I don't know how good the optimiser is.

   `Dim sValue as String: sValue = Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value`
3. When you do formatting - use `With`, so you speed up the referencing:

   `With Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB")
       .Interior.ColorIndex = 56
       .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
       .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
   End With`

Comment: Hi. Does WITH really speed up references, performance-wise?  I thought it was just a coding aid?

Comment: It used to in VB6 - that's what I am sure about. Does it help in Excel 2013? I will check it :)

Comment: Hi, when using the 'with' statement then the formats required the error 'end of statement appears'. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Ah! End With, not End if - sorry

Comment: I did several tests and "With" can speed the code - depending on number of lines within the statement. If it is more than four - it improves performance. (Tested on Excel 2007)

Answer (score 0):

Before running your macro delete empty rows from excel sheet. You can find empty rows by Cntrl+End. Press control+end, delete empty rows and save your sheet and then run macro. This will help you to run your macro fast as well as reduce the size too,

Answer (score -1):

You have three If blocks checking for the same condition it seems.  I've consolidated it here.  Replace those three with this:

**EDIT 2:** I've actually pulled out what I had and replaced the whole subroutine.  I'm replacing references to current cell in A with a string variable.  Not sure how much extra time it adds, but I'm sure the resolving of the cell reference is overhead.  Might as well read it once and just store it.  Sill not sure if the string comparisons themselves can be done faster.

```
Sub FillColumns()

    Dim i, LastRow
    Dim strCellA As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    LastRow = Sheets("Main").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 40 To LastRow 'start row number
        strCellA = Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "A").Value

        If  strCellA = "CURLEW C-Curlew Allocation" _
            Or strCellA = "COOK-Anasuria allocation" _
            Or strCellA = "SCOTER-Shearwater Allocation" _
            Or strCellA = "MERGANSER-Shearwater Alloc." _
            Or strCellA = "PENGUIN-Brent C Allocation" _
            Or strCellA = "STARLING-Shearwater Alloc." _
            Or strCellA = "HOWE-Nelson allocation" _
            Or strCellA = "ANASURIA-Fulmar" _
            Or strCellA = "BRENT ALPHA-Flags Gas" _
            Or strCellA = "BRENT BRAVO-Flags Gas" _
            Or strCellA = "BRENT CHARLIE-Brent" _
            Or strCellA = "BRENT CHARLIE-Flags" _
            Or strCellA = "BRENT DELTA-Flags Gas" _
            Or strCellA = "U500-St Fergus" _
            Or strCellA = "BACTON SEAL-SEAL" _
            Or strCellA = "CURLEW-Fulmar" _
            Or strCellA = "GANNET-Central" _
            Or strCellA = "GANNET-Fulmar" _
            Or strCellA = "MOSSMORRAN-Plants" _
            Or strCellA = "U3000-St Fergus" _
            Or strCellA = "NELSON-Forties Oil" _
            Or strCellA = "NELSON-Fulmar" _
            Or strCellA = "SHEARWATER-Forties Oil" _
            Or strCellA = "SHEARWATER-SEAL" Then
                Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Else:   Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
                Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
                Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Interior.ColorIndex = 56
        End If

        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "Z").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous


        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AA").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous

        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, "AB").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Next i

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This already should be much faster.  There's probably a faster way to do the string comparisons as well.  Let me think about it.

**EDIT 1:** Just looking at the code, I pulled all the stuff that was similar in both branches out so that will always run.